# String compare when using new String() in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Sometimes I need to make sure that a variable is a String. I used to do that by using the operator new String(value).

However, when I do that, the comparison doesn't work. For example:

```
var dude = new String("dude");
var dude2 = new String("dude");
console.log(dude == dude2); //will print 'false'
```

How to make string comparison when using the "new String()"?

I'm using JS as in the Google Apps Script

Answer (score 1):

you can do that:

```
dude.toString() == dude2.toString()
```

Comment: That's a good workaround. But still, why can't we compare two variables when we used the new String(value) to define them?

Answer (score 1):

This is the reason why 'dude' and 'dude2' are unequal:

```
var dude = new String("dude");
var dude2 = new String("dude");

console.log(typeof dude)    //object
console.log(typeof dude2)   //object
```

you can do it like this:

```
 var dude = String('dude');
 var dude2 = String('dude');
 dude === dude2  //true
```